# Abrir PDF alojado en el telefono con PhoneGap

Tags: android, html5, ios, pdf, phonegap

Tengo en mi dispositivo varios PDFs para la aplicación que estoy diseñando, lo intenté con el plugin `inAppBrowser` y el evento `window.open` pero no funcionó.

Mi código ahora mismo es asi:

```
<a href="#" window.open('pdf/visitas/Listado_2015_Guias_Zamora.pdf, '_system', 
          'location=yes');> 
Visitas 2016
</a>
```

¿Alguna otra propuesta?

Comment: Hola Alberto, podrías por favor editar tu pregunta y colocar la solución como una respuesta? Así será más fácil para otros usuarios con tu mismo problema encontrar ayuda. Gracias y bienvenido a SOes!

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré solución a este problema. Bastaba con añadir `onClick="` y sustituir el recurso por un enlace a la web quedando de esta manera:

```
    <h3><a href="#" onClick="window.open('http://www.zamora-turismo.com/pdf/visitas/Listado_2017_Guias_Zamora.pdf', '_blank', 'location=yes')"> Guías Zamora. </a></h3>
```